# SQL Server 2008 merge all rows into one

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have one column in my query and multiple rows (100+). I need to have the rows combined with only a space between so that I end up with one row.

Example:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Would actually be

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: @JNevill The title says 2008, but the question I marked as duplicate has answers for 2005+.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use `STUFF` function.

```
CREATE TABLE T (Id int)

INSERT INTO t VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO t VALUES (2);
INSERT INTO t VALUES (3);
INSERT INTO t VALUES (4);
INSERT INTO t VALUES (5);
```

**Query**

```
SELECT 
  STUFF((
    SELECT ' ' + CAST(Id AS VARCHAR(MAX))  
    FROM T
    FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)')
  ,1,0,'')
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=17216809bd8697d34228b1650b700643)